# Подмена ссылок сервером

Tags: веб-сервер, трафик

Есть ли варианты чтобы часть файлов которые запрашивает веб-браузер брать из локального хранилища?

**Например**:

Если ссылка на файл подходит под определенную маску - ссылка заменяется на локальную, иначе - запрашивается в интернете.

> если это ссылка http://www.mycompany.com/reports/sales01.pdf - то
>   браузеру отдается http://localhost/reports/sales01.pdf а иначе этот
>   файл уже запрашивается в интернете, например
>   http://www.mycompany.com/img/logo.jpg

Comment: Автор, поясните пожалуйста, под локальным хранилищем подразумевается именно localhost? Я правильно понимаю, что на компьютере клиента установлен WEB сервер?

Comment: имел в виду чтобы при открытии сайта часть файлов могли просто лежать у меня на ноутбуке. мне это больше для отладки веб-сайта. загрузка файлов на сервер после их изменения занимает достаточно много времени и поэтому хочу у себя настроить окружение так чтобы эти файлы лежали просто у меня. и потом, когда буду уверен что все работает как нужно - буду закидывать уже. ищу как это можно реализовать например через плагин для браузера или через локальный прокси-сервер

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните тога в вопросе, что именно Вам нужно. Требования о прокси или плагине не были описаны в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью `mod_rewrite`. Пример реализации:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not an existing dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not an existing file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mycompany.com/img/logo.jpg [L]
```

> *[по материалам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618751/mod-rewrite-check-if-php-file-exists) сообщества*

Разберем построчно, если осталось что-то непонятным:

1. Проверяется, есть ли каталог, который запрашивает браузер (можно исключить)
2. Проверяется, есть ли файл, согласно запросу браузера
3. Если ничего не найдено - производит редирект на http://www.mycompany.com/img/logo.jpg
4. Если запрошенный файл существует на сервере, то редиректа не будет и сервер передаст файл.

Больше информации можно посмотреть на оф. сайте в разделе [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

---

**UPD**:

Вчитавшись в вопрос, я понял, что может быть второй вариант, когда у клиента развернут HTTP сервер, и нужно брать файлы с него. Тогда `mod_rewrite` правила будут примерно такими:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/reports/(.*)" "http://localhost/reports/$1" [L]
```

Соответственно, если запрошенный адрес попадает под фильтр `/reports/*` — отдается ссылка на локальный WEB-сервер клиента.

Comment: спасибо за подсказки, это были конфиги для апача?

Comment: Да, эту конфигурацию можно прописать как в apache.conf, так и в .htaccess